# Why is this variable out of scope? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, syntax, scope, mutable

I'll get right to it (I removed a bunch of extraneous code, in case this looks a little funny -- trying to make this a MCVE):

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering 

    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let x0 = read (input!!0) :: Int
    x <- newIORef x0
    loop

loop :: IO ()
loop = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let the_dir = input_line :: String 

    putStrLn x

    loop
```

Just to test it I tried outputting x and it's saying it's out of scope. Why? How do I fix it so it is in scope? I need to access the variables but I also need to have them initialized before I enter the loop for the first time.

Comment: Can you make `loop` accept an input parameter and pass `x` to it?

Comment: I don't know how, but I would assume that is a valid way to do it

Comment: More important, what are you trying to do that needs `IORef` and such?

Comment: I have a game loop that runs over and over again and I need to read input and update values / output accordingly, I have no idea how you're supposed to do that if everything is immutable

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can update your question with the above, and provide some sample data so that we could see another solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `x` a parameter.

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering 

    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let x0 = read (input!!0) :: Int
    x <- newIORef x0
    loop x

loop :: Int -> IO ()
loop x = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let the_dir = input_line :: String 

    putStrLn $ show x

    loop
```

Or simply use `forever`.

```
import Control.Monad

...

    x <- newIORef x0
    forever $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let the_dir = input_line :: String 

        putStrLn $ show x
```

Comment: This won't type check. Above, `x` is an `IORef Int`, then is used as a `String`. With slightly more work it should work, though.

Comment: @chi I changed the parameter to IORef Int -- how do I get it to print? I tried `print $ x` and `print (readIORef x)` etc, nothing is working

Comment: @user8930358 Try `print =<< readIORef x` or split the read and the print: as in `do .... ; xVal <- readIORef x ; print xVal`

Comment: @chi I have to print two of them on the same line with a space separator, to be specific, will `print =<< readIORef x` syntax let me do that or do I have to do some string conversion thing using your second method?

Comment: Looks like `printf "%d %d" x_out y_out` works after doing `x_out <- readIORef x` and importing `Text.Printf` although I don't know if this is nonstandard

Comment: @user8930358 That's OK too. `putStrLn (show x_out ++ " " ++ show y_out)` is more common, though.